# How to design and implement function template specialization properly?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, sfinae, type-traits

I want to implement some read functions from `std::ifstream`.
It needs to separate between pod type and the others. (currently `std::string`)

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type>
T read(std::ifstream& fin);

template <>
std::string read<std::string, void>(std::ifstream& fin);

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("test", std::ios::binary);
    int x = read<int>(fin);
    std::string str = read<std::string, void>(fin);
}
```

I want to remove '`void`' from the template argument when I invoke the read for `std::string`.
How can I get it?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update(2017/09/14)**

I got a hint from EC++ and tried to implement the following codes.

```
    template <bool B>
    struct is_fundamental {
        enum { value = B };
    };

    template <typename T>
    static T doRead(std::ifstream& fin, is_fundamental<true>);

    template <typename T>
    static T doRead(std::ifstream& fin, is_fundamental<false>);

    template <>
    static std::string doRead<std::string>(std::ifstream& fin, is_fundamental<false>);

    template <typename T>
    static T read(std::ifstream& fin) {
        return doRead<T>(fin, is_fundamental<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>());
    }


    int main()
    {
        std::string filename("./test.dat");
        std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ios::binary);

        read<int>(fin);
        read<std::string>(fin);
        read<std::vector<int>>(fin);

        return 0;
    }
```

Invoking for each read<> gets the proper function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that isn't possible to partial specialize a function.

What about the use of structs?

If you write `read` ad follows,

```
template <typename T>
struct read 
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value 
                        && std::is_pod<T>::value, T>::type
      operator() (std::ifstream & fin)
    { /* do something; return a T */ }
 };

template <>
struct read<std::string>
 {
   std::string operator() (std::ifstream & fin)
    { /* do something; return a string */ }
 };
```

you have a generic version of the `read` struct, where the `operator()` is enabled only of the template type is `POD`, and a specialized version for `std::string` (and you can add other specializations of `read`; partial specialization also).

The drawback is you have to change the call of `read()` in this way

```
int x = read<int>{}(fin);
std::string str = read<std::string>{}(fin);
```

that is, defining an object (`read<T>{}`).

If you prefer to use a static member inside read -- by example, `func()` -- you can avoid the need of object creation but you have to call it in this way

```
int x = read<int>::func(fin);
std::string str = read<std::string>::func(fin);
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct read 
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value 
                        && std::is_pod<T>::value, T>::type
      operator() (std::ifstream & fin)
    { T ret ; std::cout << "POD!" << std::endl ; fin >> ret ; return ret; }
 };

template <>
struct read<std::string>
 {
   std::string operator() (std::ifstream & fin)
    { std::string ret ; std::cout << "string!" << std::endl; fin >> ret ;
      return ret; }
 };

int main()
 {
   std::ifstream fin("test", std::ios::binary);
   int x = read<int>{}(fin);                    // write POD!
   std::string str = read<std::string>{}(fin);  // write string!
   //auto read<std::vector<int>>{}(fin);        // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @TwisTeDStRiDeR if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: *"The drawback is you have to change the call of read() in this way"*. You may bypass the drawback with a level of indirection:
`template <typename T> T read(std::ifstream & fin) { return my_read<T>{}(fin); }` (with correct renaming).

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can use overload and tag dispatching:

```
template <typename> struct Tag {};

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<T>::value>* = nullptr>
T read(Tag<T>, std::ifstream& fin);

std::string read(Tag<std::string>, std::ifstream& fin);
```

And use it:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("test", std::ios::binary);
    int x = read(Tag<int>{}, fin);              // write POD!
    auto str = read(Tag<std::string>{}, fin);   // write string!
    //auto v = read(Tag<std::vector<int>>{}, fin); // compilation error
}
```